# samba mangled filename algorithm (hash2) to unix filename in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, hash, samba

my task is very simple, I have a list of files with some of them mangled by samba that I have to process in a linux environment using some python scripts.
I want to build a function that converts the samba hash2 mangled form into the original unix path.

After reading the smb configuration of the server, mangled files are generated by using hash2 and 1 character prefix + magic char '~'.

In samba docs : https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html
there is no mention of how hash2 is computed, and I can't find any answer elsewhere.

Moreover, is the full path used to compute the hash2 or only the last directory name?
for example:

```
Z:/aaa/bbb/ccc/T3XBGA~5/3 - Two Shell - LabBaby™.mp3 //mangled form

/aaa/bbb/ccc/Two Shell - SoulCity E.P./3 - Two Shell - LabBaby™.mp3 //original unix path
```

as you see mangling occurs because only one file of this folder is using a unicode character, but what part of the unix path is used to compute this hash? and how to make the reverse conversion ?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT :**  While reading samba source code, I realized that I was wrong saying dir name was mangled because of the unicode ™ character, in this case, it was mangled because directory name has 2 dots and end with '.'

```c
    // mangle_hash2.c
    if (dot_p) {
        /* if the extension contains any illegal characters or
           is too long or zero length then we treat it as part
           of the prefix */
        for (i=0; i<4 && dot_p[i+1]; i++) {
            if (! FLAG_CHECK(dot_p[i+1], FLAG_ASCII)) {
                dot_p = NULL;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == 0 || i == 4) {
            dot_p = NULL;
        }
```

https://github.com/samba-team/samba/blob/24fb40a812184fa57458ae9f0f4ffbced1dee09a/source3/smbd/mangle_hash2.c#L707

Comment: See https://github.com/samba-team/samba/blob/master/source3/smbd/mangle.c

Comment: Thanks , I did not think about read samba source, I will edit my question with my implementation.

Comment: No worries. The hash2 implementation in particular is over at https://github.com/samba-team/samba/blob/master/source3/smbd/mangle_hash2.c